# MySQL create index Error#1089

Tags: mysql

MySQL create index Error#1089

**ERROR 1089 (HY000): Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys**

```
CREATE TABLE t3
(
id INT NOT NULL,
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
info VARCHAR(255),
INDEX MultiIdx(id, name, age(100))
);
```

How to fix this error? thank you.

Comment: `INDEX MultiIdx(id, name, age)`

Comment: Why do you use `age(100)`, what do you expect that to do?

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE t3
(
id INT NOT NULL,
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
info VARCHAR(255),
key MultiIdx(id, name, age)
);
```

Comment: Don't dump "fixed" code. Explain what was wrong with the OP's code and how your changes fix that.

Comment: Thanks for teaching.@CodeCaster